# How to convert an XML entity back to a character

Tags: php, xml

I'm working with XML files, and sometimes I'm facing with an XML encoding problem, for example, instead of `ö` I'm getting `&#246;`. How can I fix this in php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `html_entity_decode()`, example (from PHP manual):

```
$orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";

$a = htmlentities($orig);

$b = html_entity_decode($a);

echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now

echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
```

And your case specifically is covered here:
http://codepad.viper-7.com/4DIrsM

**NB:** The function's 3rd parameter is the character set encoding. By default it is ISO-8859-1 (according to PHP manual), but most websites are in UTF-8, so you need to set the parameter yourself as I did above.